# Looping through textbox controls in a panel control

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream

I'm trying to create a csv with order details that pull from textboxes. I have panel control that has 12 textboxes sitting inside it and I want to write the text of each textbox onto a new line in a csv but nothing is happening, the file gets created but with no text.

Here's my code:

```
FileStream file = new FileStream(string.Format(@"Z:\Stream\order{0}.csv", txtName.Text),FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(file);
wr.WriteLine(txtName.Text);
wr.WriteLine(txtOrderRef.Text);

List<TextBox> textboxControls = new List<TextBox>();

foreach (TextBox controls in Panel1.Controls)
{
    textboxControls.Add(controls);
}

foreach(TextBox c in textboxControls)
{
    wr.WriteLine(c.Text);
    Label1.Text = c.Text + "<br />";

}

wr.Close();
```

Comment: `panelName.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()` will give you a list of all the textboxes, do your textboxes have text in them?

Comment: Hmm are 2 loops neccessary? Btw you I recommend using try and catch with StreamWriter.

Comment: Yes Sayse my text box's have text in them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd imagine your problem lies in the closing of the stream, you should use a `using` block

```
using(StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(file))
{
    wr.WriteLine(txtName.Text);
    wr.WriteLine(txtOrderRef.Text);

    foreach (var control in Panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        wr.WriteLine(control.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to loop twice, also you need to check if the control is a Textbox, try using the `is` construct like so:

```
FileStream file = new FileStream(string.Format(@"Z:\Stream\order{0}.csv",       txtName.Text),FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(file);
wr.WriteLine(txtName.Text);
wr.WriteLine(txtOrderRef.Text);

List<TextBox> textboxControls = new List<TextBox>();

foreach (var control in Panel1.Controls)
{
   if(control is TextBox)
   {
      Textbox tb = control as TextBox;
      wr.WriteLine(tb.Text);
      textboxControls.Add(tb); //not needed in this context, but may be used in code elsewhere
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris tried both answers and they both worked